# trying to get "é" character to print out correctly

Tags: php, html-entities, html-escape-characters

I am trying to take the rss/xml feed from itunes and I have noticed that artist and songs that have special charters like `é` like in `beyoncé` is showing as `BeyoncÃ©`

I have tried the following to get it to show correctly but unsucessfully I have Googled searched and searched on here for the correct answer but sadly not working.

here is what I have tried - I maybe way off.

```
echo html_entity_decode($entry->imartist, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

here is the full code

```
function itunes(){
$itunes_feed = "https://itunes.apple.com/au/rss/topsongs/limit=100/explicit=true/xml";
$itunes_feed = file_get_contents($itunes_feed);
$itunes_feed = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $itunes_feed);
$itunes_xml = new SimpleXMLElement($itunes_feed);
$itunes_entry = $itunes_xml->entry;

foreach($itunes_entry as $entry){
    echo html_entity_decode($entry->title."<br>", ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
    echo html_entity_decode($entry->imartist, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
    echo "<br><br>";
    // Get the value of the entry ID, by using the 'im' namespace within the <id> attribute
    $entry_id['im'] = $entry->id->attributes('im', TRUE);
    echo (string)$entry_id['im']['artist'];
    //echo $entry_id['artist']."<br>";
}
}
```

Comment: what charset is your page using? did you add the right utf-8 meta? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#Examples

Comment: You are likely reading a UTF-8 encoded feed with a single byte encoding (such as ISO 8859-1).

Comment: You would appear to be converting to UTF-8 successfully, but then whatever you're talking to isn't happy about it.  If you're trying to write _to_ HTML, then you're going the wrong way (should be encoding rather than decoding).

Comment: Getting `Ã` in output is a major clue that your client is running in a single-byte charset, such as iso8859, and you're dumping raw utf text into that iso8859 environment.

Comment: So how would one go about fixing this issue? I take it is a server issue not a coding issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feed is in valid UTF-8, you shouldn't need to decode it with `html_entity_decode`. What happens if you add a `<meta charset="utf-8" />` in the `<head>` of HTML page ?

Comment: As mentioned before, you are receiving UTF-8 encoded text (multibyte characters). Assuming this is going to a web page, declaring the page to be UTF-8 should display these characters correctly. **However**, make sure everything else on the page is either plain ASCII or is UTF-8. Watch out for page editors that insert Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) or Windows-1252 non-ASCII characters, such as `&nbsp;` (non-breaking/required space) or &raquo; (>>).